# How should I pass settings to a module in Perl that also exports symbols?

Tags: perl

In [`Test::Version`](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aVersion) I want to add configuration settings that allow one to toggle certain features. I'm thinking about passing an anonymous hash to a custom `import` like so.

```
use Test::Version 1.2 qw( version_ok ), { is_strict => '1', has_version => '0' };
```

other options I've thought of include package variables (though more ugly in my opinion).

```
use Test::Version 1.2 qw( version_ok );
$Test::Version::IS_STRICT   = 1;
$Test::Version::HAS_VERSION = 0;
```

or maybe using some other kind of operator to denote config settings on import, though I'm not sure exactly how to implement this.

```
use Test::Version 1.2 qw( version_ok ), +is_strict => '1', +has_version => '0';
```

Keep in mind that this has a simple functional interface, so passing objects, or using config files is overkill. Any preferences? or other suggestions?

Comment: Check out [Sub::Exporter](http://p3rl.org/Sub::Exporter).

Comment: @BradGilbert I found Sub::Exporter to be a bit complicated and powerful for what I'm trying to achieve. Also, I wasn't able to actually discern how I would use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I would stay away from changing the normal workings of `import()`. I've never seen a module mix exporting and configuration at the same time (maybe you have, though), so leave those out (options 1 and 3). I think you are right in thinking that option 2 isn't too pretty. That leaves us with none of those options.

I think instead of this you should just allow calling `version_ok` and `version_all_ok` with the options hash.

```
version_ok({ is_string => 1, has_version => 0 });
```

Clear and standard, nothing odd going on.  From the way it seems like the module is going to be used this isn't a burden on the user (since there will normally only be one call to this in the entire test suite).

Answer (score 0):

Besides passing the options to imported functions as aparker42 mentioned you could simply write a function `configure` within your package and deal with the options there.

```
package Test::version ;

#use vars qw($is_string $has_version) ;
# Instead of multiple configuration variables I personally would
# bundle them in a hash
# Filling the hash with defaults ... and it also makes the configure easier
use vars qw(%options) ;
%options = ( is_string => 0 ,
             has_version => 1 ) ;

sub configure {
  my ( $opthr ) = @_ ;
  foreach my $key ( keys %{ $opthr } ) {
    if( exists $options{$key} ) {
      # Check if the given variable exists in the %options hash
      $options{$key} = $opthr->{$key} ;
    }
  } 
}

# Rest of the code here ...

1;
```

And using the module with

```
use Test::version qw(version_ok) ;
Test::version::configure( { is_string => 1 } ) ;
```